Return list of which column ID and year has missing (NA) data only for all the other columns in R



ID
Year
Maths_sub
Eng_sub
Chem_sub
Comp_sub




1
2010
20
15
12
NA


2
2015
17
20
14
16


3
2012
NA
17
12
NA


4
2015
14
13
NA
NA


5
2016
NA
NA
NA
NA


6
2015
NA
NA
NA
NA



Hello, I want to know for the above table which ID and for which Year only people with all subject columns are NA. Results should be like below:



ID
Year




5
2016


6
2015



I have tried something along the lines of the code below but it is not giving me the ideal answer.
df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("sub"), is.na)) %>%  
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "sub") %>%  
  filter(value) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(`Missing Variables` = toString(sub))

Also as an extra I would like to know if there is a way to mutate across only certain columns, for example only Maths and Comp and seeing which ID and Year has both these subjects NA?
Thank you very much!

base R approach
Instinctively I would use rowSums() applied to is.na() of the columns in question.
sub_cols <- grep("sub$", names(dat), value = TRUE)

dat[
    rowSums(is.na(dat[sub_cols])) == length(sub_cols),
    c("ID", "Year")
]
#   ID Year
# 5  5 2016
# 6  6 2015

dplyr approach
I actually find it quite awkward to do matrix operations using dplyr, but this is how I would do it:
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    filter(
        rowSums(!is.na(select(., ends_with("sub")))) == 0
    ) %>%
    select(ID, Year)
#   ID Year
# 5  5 2016
# 6  6 2015

data.table approach
For completeness, here's a data.table approach. You can use patterns("sub$") to select columns ending in in "sub" and you can use rowSums() with .SD, so overall I think it's the nicest approach:
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

dat[
    dat[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)) == 0, .SDcols = patterns("sub$")],
    .(ID, Year)
]
#       ID  Year
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     5  2016
# 2:     6  2015

Data
dat <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Year = c(2010L, 2015L, 2012L, 2015L, 
2016L, 2015L), Maths_sub = c(20L, 17L, NA, 14L, NA, NA), Eng_sub = c(15L, 
20L, 17L, 13L, NA, NA), Chem_sub = c(12L, 14L, 12L, NA, NA, NA
), Comp_sub = c(NA, 16L, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))


Another alternative with base R similar to yours: dat[rowSums(is.na(dat[,-c(1,2)]))==4, 1:2]

@JilberUrbina it's certainly shorter but too many magic numbers for my liking.

Another option is to filter the rows where all values are NA per group like this:
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  filter(if_all(Maths_sub:Comp_sub, ~is.na(.)))%>%
  select(-c(Maths_sub:Comp_sub))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>      ID  Year
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     5  2016
#> 2     6  2015

Created on 2024-05-08 with reprex v2.1.0
